# Change element in matrix from 0 to 1 when event takes place

Tags: python, matrix, pygame

I've recently written a program with a list, but now I need to change the list into a matrix. I programmed a grid by drawing rectangles. Now I want to change the color of the rectangle when I click on it. In my program with the list everything worked just fine, but now I have to use a matrix, because I need a matrix for the rest of my program. I've already got a matrix with all zeros, but now I want to change the 0 in to a 1 when I click on a rectangle.

```
x = 5
y = 5

height = 30
width = 50
size = 20
color = (255,255,255)
new_color = (0,255,0)

screen.fill((0,0,0))

def draw_grid():
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x * (size + 1),y * (size + 1),size,size)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)
            x += 20
        y += 20

rects = [[0 for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
draw_grid()


while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()


    if menu == 'start':   

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for i,(rect,color) in enumerate(rects):
                if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    rects[i] = (rect,new_color)

        for rect,color in rects:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the code I used with the list, but I've already replaced the list with a matrix. When I run this code it gives an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: rect is a list of lists, but you treat it as a list of 2-tuples with `for rect,color in rects:`. That doesn't work.

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: Should the 0s and 1s in the `rects` list represent the colors of the rects? If you don't want to store the `pygame.Rect`s in the list anymore you need to change the collision detection and drawing code.

Comment: @AV13 that depends on which of these you want. What is `Rects` supposed to be? You fill it with lists of zeroes early in your code, but then try to extract a `rect,color` tuple later on. You will have to decide which of these you want. If you want the tuple, fill it with tuples instead of lists. If you want the lists of zeroes, change the for loop to deal with those.

I can't tell you what you want there, as I don't know what you're going for.

Comment: The 0s and 1s should represent the color: 0 = color, 1 = new_color. If I press on a rectangle, the 0 should change to a 1. After that, I want to draw the new matrix, and all the rectangles that have a one should be in the new_color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw the rects you can iterate over the matrix and depending on the value (0 or 1) draw a white rect or a green rect. (You could also store the colors directly in the matrix, but I don't know if you want to do something else with it.)

To change the color of the clicked cells, you can easily calculate the indexes of the cells by floor dividing the mouse coords by `(size+1)`, e.g. `x = mouse_x // (size+1)`. Then just set `matrix[y][x] = 1`.

```
import sys
import pygame


WHITE = pygame.Color('white')
GREEN = pygame.Color('green')


def draw_grid(screen, matrix, size):
    """Draw rectangles onto the screen to create a grid."""
    # Iterate over the matrix. First rows then columns.
    for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for x, color in enumerate(row):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*(size+1), y*(size+1), size, size)
            # If the color is white ...
            if color == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect)
            # If the color is green ...
            elif color == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect)


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    height = 30
    width = 50
    size = 20  # Cell size.
    matrix = [[0 for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            # To change the color, calculate the indexes
            # of the clicked cell like so:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = mouse_x // (size+1)
            y = mouse_y // (size+1)
            matrix[y][x] = 1

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Now draw the grid. Pass all needed values to the function.
        draw_grid(screen, matrix, size)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I nedded! I have one more question:  in the draw_grid-function you first do: for y, row in enumerate(matrix). Why do you use row? And on the next line color?

Comment: `row` are the sublists of the matrix which contain the 0s and 1s. In the next line I iterate over `row` (the sublist) to get the 0s and 1s which stand for the color, so I named the variable `color` (couldn't think of a better name ;)).